# How to randomize quiz questions order in multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, random

```
var questions =[
new Question ("Who is the president of Czech Republic?", ["Donald Trump", "Andrej Kiska", "Milos Zeman", "Angela Merkel"], "Milos Zeman"),
new Question ("The capital of Czech Republic is:", ["Brno", "Ostrava", "Hradec Kralove", "Prague"], "Prague"),
new Question ("Which food is not common Czech food?", ["Cevapcici", "Svickova", "Trdelnik", "Tatarak"], "Cevapcici")];
var quiz = new Quiz(questions);
populate();
```

How do I randomize the order of the questions in this quiz? Here is the working sample:

https://jsfiddle.net/yhosftnt/

Answer (score 0):

Sort them by using random numbers ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cvs59fnk/)):

```
this.questions = [].concat(questions).sort(function() {
    return Math.random() - Math.random();
});
```

The `[].concat(questions)` creates a new array, so the original array won't be changed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very elegant solution!

Comment: One more small thing, since it is an array of strings how would I limit a number of random questions to pop up? Let's say in this example I want just 2 out of 3 questions to show up?

Comment: Slice the array after the sort - `.slice(0, number of questions)`